# How to define Terminal?

Tags: xtermjs

I got the example from the official xterm site

```js
<!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/xterm/css/xterm.css" />
      <script src="node_modules/xterm/lib/xterm.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="terminal"></div>
      <script>
        var term = new Terminal();
        term.open(document.getElementById('terminal'));
        term.write('Hello from \x1B[1;3;31mxterm.js\x1B[0m $ ')
      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

but I always got a "Uncaught ReferenceError: Terminal is not defined"

How I can define Terminal?

Comment: I'm using express, and the routes of node_modules/xterm/css/xterm.css & node_modules/xterm/lib/xterm.js is getting 404

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Well you already answered it yourself - "node_modules/xterm/lib/xterm.js is getting 404". Maybe fix the paths to the correct ones?